# reading this text in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Hi I am trying to read this text using a file input stream or some sort:

```
E^@^@<a^R@^@@^FÌø<80>è^AÛ<80>è  ^F \^DÔVn3Ï^@^@^@^@ ^B^VÐXâ^@^@^B^D^E´^D^B^H
IQRÝ^@^@^@^@^A^C^C^GE^@^@<^@^@@^@@^F.^K<80>è    ^F<80>è^AÛ^DÔ \»4³ÕVn3Ð ^R^V J  ^@^@^B^D^E´^D^B^H
^@g<9f><86>IQRÝ^A^C^C^GE^@^@4a^S@^@@^FÌÿ<80>è^AÛ<80>è   ^F \^DÔVn3Ð»4³Ö<80>^P^@.<8f>F^@^@^A^A^H
IQRÞ^@g<9f><86>E^@^A±,Q@^@@^F^@E<80>è   ^F<80>è^AÛ^DÔ \»4³ÖVn3Ð<80>^X^@.^NU^@^@^A^A^H
^@g<9f><87>
```

Here's the code I tried to read it with, but I am getting a bunch of 0s.

```
    #include <stdio.h>   /* required for file operations */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int n;
  FILE *fr;
  unsigned char c;
  if (argc != 2) {
    perror("Usage: summary <FILE>");
    return 1;
  }

  fr = fopen (argv[1], "rt");  /* open the file for reading */

  while (1 == 1){
    read(fr, &c, sizeof(c));
    printf("<0x%x>\n", c);
  }
  fclose(fr);  /* close the file prior to exiting the routine */
}
```

What's wrong with my code? I think I am not reading the file correctly.

Comment: What is encoding of file? UTF8? Unicode?

Comment: I have no idea, how to do u tell?

Comment: Wait, are you using a `FILE *` and passing it to `read()`? `read()` takes an `int fd`, unless this is some platform that doesn't?

Comment: Open it in hex editor first and post hex output.

Comment: Not sure...if I want to just read 1 byte at a time, how would I do it?

Comment: @SuperString: `getc` or `fgetc` would be an excellent choice for reading single bytes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [decipher this text in c/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860365/decipher-this-text-in-c-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your's didn't compile for me, but I made a few fixes and it's right as rain ;-)

```
  #include <stdio.h>   /* required for file operations */

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int n;
    FILE *fr;
    unsigned char c;
    if (argc != 2) {
      perror("Usage: summary <FILE>");
      return 1;
    }

    fr = fopen (argv[1], "rt");  /* open the file for reading */

    while (!feof(fr)){  // can't read forever, need to stop when reading is done
      // my ubuntu didn't have read in stdio.h, but it does have fread
      fread(&c, sizeof(c),1, fr);
      printf("<0x%x>\n", c);
    }
    fclose(fr);  /* close the file prior to exiting the routine */
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `fopen()` to open your file, which returns a `FILE *`, and `read()` to read it, which takes an `int`. You need to either use `open()` and `read()` together, or `fopen()` and `fread()`. You can't mix these together.

To clarify, `fopen()` and `fread()` make use of `FILE` pointers, which are a different way to access and a different abstraction than straight-up file descriptors. `open()` and `read()` make use of "raw" file descriptors, which are a notion understood by the operating system.

While not related to the program's failure here, your `fclose()` call must also match. In other words, `fopen()`, `fread()`, and `fclose()`, or `open()`, `read()`, and `close()`.

Comment: I'm guessing that's a typo, since the code wouldn't even compile as posted.  `open` would be an undefined identifier, since its header isn't included, and then the parameter would be the wrong type and can't be implicitly converted.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That might be right, now that you mention it. Though, even with `fread()` then, it should at least function and print the proper things; it just wouldn't terminate, what with the `1 == 1` and all. But yeah, you might be right. Perhaps OP can enlighten us.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like text to me.  So use the `"r"` mode to `fopen`, not `"rt"`.

Also, `^@` represents `'\0'`, so you probably will read a bunch of zeros in any case.  But not ALL zeros.

Comment: Your file has zeros in it.  Dump the file using `hexdump` or `xxd`.

Comment: @SuperString: Two well-known programs that dump hex values of the file contents.